# How to have isometric projection be a counter-clockwise rotation of flat 2d view

Tags: javascript, math, isometric

I am making this isometric projection of a 2D table in a Javascript project. I'm calculating my isometric coordinates (from cartesian) with the following function:

```
var isoX = x - y;
var isoY = (x + y) / 2;
```

The problem I have is that this rotates everything clock-wise:

```
AB
CD
```

becomes

```
 A
C B
 D
```

Instead, I would like it to become

```
 B
A D
 C
```

Can I adjust the function above somehow to achieve this? If not, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Swap the signs.

Comment: Is the table square? Is it centered on (0,0) or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to rotate the table *before* the projection step.

The [2D rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for 90 degrees counter clockwise is

```
[ 0 1]
[-1 0]
```

Putting it in code, this transformation rotates everything around (0,0) 90 degrees ccw:

```
var transformedX = y;
var transformedY = -x;
```

Then, simply use the transformed coordinates for the projection.

```
var isoX = transformedX - transformedY;
var isoY = (transformedX + transformedY) / 2;
```